# Expandable card on flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to create this expandable card (design screenshots are below), I've already created a card with those connectors, but I can't make that Card an expandable Card. Any idea of how can I achieve that design? (it should expand when the "Más conectores" blue text is tapped)...

This is my card:

```
 const FilterTitle(text: "CONECTOR"),
            const SizedBox(height: 15),
            Card(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
              ),
              elevation: 10,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: GridView.count(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    crossAxisCount: 3,
                    children: List.generate(chargerTypes.length, (index) {
                      return Column(children: [
                        InkWell(
                          splashColor: Colors.grey,
                          child: Image(
                              image: NetworkImage(
                                  chargerTypes[index].imageLink)),
                        ),
                        Center(
                            child: Text(
                          chargerTypes[index].description,
                        ))
                      ]);
                    })),
              ),
            ),
```

Collapsed card figma design

[image]

Expanded card Figma design

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all create a `bool` variable like below

```
bool isExpanded = false;
```

then when tapping on Mas conectores (as shown in 2nd image)

use like this

```
onTap: () {
    setState(() {
      isExpanded =true;
    });
},
```

then use `GridView.builder` instead of `GridView.count(` and in `itemCount` of `GridView.builder` use like below

```
itemCount: isExpanded ?(chargerTypes.length > ? 3 : chargerTypes.length):chargerTypes.length,
```

Comment: Could you share a example? I'm kinda new at flutter and I've never used GridView.builder... Thank you btw

Comment: @AlvaroDosio when you click on expand more, `isExpanded`   becomes true , `itemCount` render the full list, else it is rendering 3 item

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Actually, i'm not realizing what to put on "gridDelegate"...

Comment: are you using `GridView.buileder`

Comment: gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 3
          ),
use it like this @AlvaroDosio